In an algebraic ring extension, is compositum of two finite subalgebras finite
Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $S$ be an $R$-algebra (not necessarily commutative),
such that it is algebraic over $R$, in the sense that for any $x\in S$, the subring $R[x]\subset S$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.
Let $A,B$ be two $R$-subalgebras in $S$ which are finitely generated $R$-modules. My question is, is their compositum $AB$ also a finitely generated $R$-module?
Here are the cases I know:

The answer is "yes" if $S$ is commutative: in this case if $\{a_1,\cdots,a_m\}$ generates $A$ and $\{b_1,\cdots,b_n\}$ generates $B$ as $R$-modules, then $\{a_ib_j\}$ generates $AB$ as $R$-module. Here the commutative condition is used.

There are counterexamples if not assuming $S/R$ is algebraic: take $G$ be a group such that there are two torsion elements $a,b$ of $G$ such that their product $ab$ is not torsion (e.g. $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$), taking $S=R[G]$, $A=R[a]$ and $B=R[b]$.


But I don't know if it's true when $S$ is not commutative but $S/R$ is algebraic. Any hints? You can assume $R$ is a field for simplicity.

There are counterexamples. This is related to the Kurosh problem:

Suppose all 1-generated subalgebras of a finitely generated associative algebra A are finite dimensional (i.e. is spanned by a finite set of elements). Is A finite dimensional?

This version is taken from Mark Sapir's book: Combinatorial algebra: syntax and
semantics, Section 4.4. The answer is negative but not easy.
Here the associative algebra $A$ is not assumed to have $1$, but we can always add $1$ to it without hurting our argument: if $x\in A$ is algebraic, then any $\lambda + x \in kI\oplus A$ is also algebraic. And given $a\in A$, the subalgebra generated by $a$ is finite dimensional iff $f(a)=0$ for some polynomial (Lemma 4.4.2 in Sapir).
Let $S=k\langle x_1,\cdots, x_n\rangle$ be a counter-example to the Kurosh problem. Consider $A=k\langle x_1\rangle$ and $B = k \langle x_2 \rangle$, if $AB$ is not finite dimensional over $k$, we are done. Otherwise, take $A=k\langle x_1, x_2\rangle$ and $B=k\langle x_3 \rangle$, etc, until we have $AB$ is not finite dimensional.
